# Robotium best practice. clickOnView vs clickOnButton

Tags: android, testing, robotium

I was wondering if it is not better to always use `solo.clickOnView(solo.getView(R.id.example_button));` to press on an button or `solo.enterText((EditText) solo.getView(R.id.example_editText), "invalidEmail");` to enter en Text.
When using the index `solo.clickOnButton(0)` to press on an button, the test will fail instant when UI has changed.

Would this still be BlackBox Testing when always using the View?

Im new to Robotium and testing itself and was wondering what other Programmers are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using IDs will be the best option, as you note not doing so will make your test incredibly fragile to nearly any UI change. You can normally take this even further using concepts like page objects (https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects is about selenium but the rough concept holds) allowing you to write tests that will be much more maintainable than in every test searching for objects using ids (if an id changes then you only have to change it in one place etc)

I think this would still be able to be deemed black box testing, but in my experience these terms are a bit useless and you should do what will work best for the system you are working on, in android ids would be your best bet.

Comment: Thanks! Im thinking the same and have started to only use ids (if possible)